# How to set probability of something happening in an if-then statement?

Tags: python

I've just started to learn to code, and I'm creating a simple interface where I say something and it responds with phrases that I've set. For example, if I say

if 'are you okay' in command:
talk('no')

It's simple, just not for me. How could I change it so there's a 50% chance that it'll say "no" and a 50% chance that it'll say "yes." Thanks for the help!

Comment: Might I suggest looking at [the `random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `random.choice()` function with the `random` module:

```
import random
answers = ['yes', 'no']

input = input('Enter in the sentence: ')
if input == 'are you okay':
    print(random.choice(answers))
```

If you wanted to have something like 75% chance of `yes` and 25% chance of `no` then just add more in the `answers` list like this:

```
answers = ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! You guys are great!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

if 'are you okay' in command:
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        talk('no')
    else:
        talk('yes')
```

That should do the trick.

The `random` module contains a large number of functions for generating different kinds of randomness (random integers in a range, random samples from a collection). What we want here is a random floating point number between 0 and 1 (well, "[0.0, 1.0)", meaning equal to or greater than zero and less than 1), so that we can think of it as a probability. Then we just check if our random number of less than 0.5, and print one if True (i.e. if our condition `random.random() < 0.5` evaluates to `True`), or the other if False (with an if-else statement).

Comment: You are an absolute life-saver. Genius, I tell you!