# Is there a neater way to implement: do this with probability p and that with probability (1-p)? (python)

Tags: python, list, probability

I am trying to implement the following in Python:
'with probability *p* randomly choose a variable from a list l and with probability *(1-p)* choose a fixed variable w'. I have an implementation based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564234/how-to-set-probability-of-something-happening-in-an-if-then-statement) which seems to work, but I was just wondering if there is a neater way of doing this? The following is for probability 50%, but I want this to work for any probability p (to 2 decimals):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

p = 0.5 # this is my probability p
r = 100*p # this transforms my probability p to an integer
q = 100*(1-p) # this transforms my probability (1-p) to an integer

v = random.choice(l) # a randomly chosen variable from a list l
w = 2 # a fixed variable

listt = []
listt.extend([v]*int(r)) # this adds a randomly chosen v to the list r times
listt.extend([w]*int(q)) # this adds w to the list q times

# I now have a list which has r elements v and q elements w

random.choice(listt)
```

Thanks!

Comment: how are you choosing a fixed variable?

Comment: The fixed variable is w = 2. I am choosing it with probability (1-p) by adding it 100*(1-p) times to a list from which I then randomly choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.random()` makes for a simpliest generator against float-value probability.

```
import random

p = 0.2

for _ in range(20):
    if random.random() < p:
        print('0') # probability p
    else:
        print('1') # probability 1-p
```

And simpliest way to emulate specifically what you were doing in your question:

```
import random
p = 0.2

v = 0
w = 1


for _ in range(20):
    print(random.choices([v, w], [p, 1-p])[0]) # [0] as choices returns a list and we only care about one value.
```

`random.choices` accepts a weights parameter. if you pass p and 1-p for each element respectively, you will get elements chosen with correct probabilities.

Comment: might be nice to use destructuring assignment and the `cum_weights` variant of `choices` here: `[x] = random.choices([v, w], cum_weights=[p, 1.]); print(x)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
from random import choice, random

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
p = 0.3
w = 2
n = 100 # the number of elements in the final result 

result = [choice(l) if random() < p else w for _ in range(n)]
```

Reproducible (thanks to `seed`) example output with `n=10`:

```
>>> from random import choice, random, seed
>>> seed(21)
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> p = 0.3
>>> w = 2
>>> n = 10
>>> result = [choice(l) if random() < p else w for _ in range(n)]
>>> result
[6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 5, 2]
```